# SystemVerilog highlight in Azure DevOps repo

Tags: azure-devops

is Azure DevOps repo able to highlight syntax SystemVerilog files ? *.sv

I have tried google, chatbotGPT any setting in AD but no results... Also checked other stack overflow topics with no results. I would appreciate any kind of help. Did somebody solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Repos text editor can recognize most of the popular test file types and provide a good highlight in these files.

For the **SystemVerilog** file (**`.sv`**), it also can highlight well in this type files.

Below is an image of what I attempt in my Azure DevOps repo. It is able to well highlight the keys, variables and commented lines in the **`.sv`** file.

[image]

Comment: my bad, I mean highlight syntax in pull requests